# Get neighboring colors in Unity shader?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, virtual-reality

How in a Unity shader like the following would I get the neighboring color values of the screen position in question? For instance, I want to apply a simple blur by using a pixel comparison matrix as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing) (though it should ideally work in VR/ stereo). Thanks!

```
float4 Frag(VaryingsDefault i) : SV_Target {
    float4 color = SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_MainTex, sampler_MainTex, i.texcoordStereo);

    // ...?

    return color;
}
```

Comment: Pretty broad topic but in general you'll want to look into post-processing effects. You can partially render your image, then finish rendering it with an extra pass once the full scene information is available.

Comment: Thanks -- I am using post-processing effects. Above is my custom shader added to Unity's PostProcessing2 Beta stack, and works in changing e.g. the color. But now I want to change the color of a pixel based on neighboring colors... Thanks for any help!